# jQuery: child elements of appended object

Tags: jquery

Is there a more elegant way of working with multiple objects within an object. For example:

```
<table class="thisTable">
    <tr class="thisRow">
        <td class="row1"></td>
        <td class="row2"></td>
        <td class="row3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Instead of doing:

```
$("table.thisTable tr.thisRow td.row1").text("Hi")
$("table.thisTable tr.thisRow td.row2").text("Mom")
$("table.thisTable tr.thisRow td.row3").text("Dad")
```

is there a method that allows:

```
$("table.thisTable tr.thisRow").function() {
    $(this).children("td.row1").text("Hi");
    $(this).children("td.row2").text("Mom");
    $(this).children("td.row3").text("Dad");
}
```

I know you don't gain anything functionally, but I have a lot of long selectors that start to get difficult to track and maintain in code.

I've been scouring the jQuery documentation, but the concept isn't jumping out at me and my Google search terms just aren't getting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thisRow').children().each(function(index, obj) {
        $(obj).text('Hi');
        });
    });
```

Will iterate through the children and allow you to address each element individually. Also, .children() only goes down one leve, where .find() will traverse multiple levels of the DOM (in case your example gets larger in practice).

Comment: This is the closest I to what I'm looking to accomplish. Can we do something along the lines of $(obj + ".row1").text("Hi")? I think this makes the each option invalid (??).

Comment: You can do the string concatenation like that. It would make sure that only class row1 was affected. If the answer helps, you can accept it(the checkmark) to let others know as well!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is cache the main selector as a variable:

```
var $tr = $("table.thisTable tr.thisRow");
$tr.find('td.row1').text('Hi');
$tr.find('td.row2').text('Hi');
$tr.find('td.row3').text('Hi');
```

Or you can group them and provide a context:

```
$('td.row1, td.row2, td.row3', 'table.thisTable tr.thisRow').text('Hi');
```

Comment: Good answer... close to what I'm hoping to accomplish. It helps with the readability of the code.

Answer (score 1):

This will select all tds under your `.thisRow` row and set their text in one line.

```
$('.thisRow td').text('Hi');
```

For reference, classes are for grouping elements together. You are using the class as an id, which individually identifies each element with a unique name. The selector works similarly to selectors in CSS if you are familiar with CSS.

Comment: I updated my example based on your answer as I don't want to set each cell to the same value, but be able to affect all cells within a row without repeating all of the table and row identifiers.

Comment: Also, I'm using the class as an ID in that my use case loads an HTML template, clones the row, and appends it while adding new data (think data grid).

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
$("table.thisTable tr.thisRow td.row1").text("Hi");
```

Comment: This is where I am now, but the depth of some of the containers is making my code unreadable. Back to my original post, code maintenance is one of the primary things I'm looking to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague, and I'm guessing it's because you don't know precisely what to ask.  But I think what you're looking for is the `$.each()` function, in addition to @Alex's answer.

```
$("table.thisTable tr.thisRow").children().each(function() {
  // "this" is the current child of tr.thisRow
  $(this).text('Hi!');
});
```

### Update

In response to your comment:  You have to remember that jQuery selectors are just strings, and therefore you can do anything you want to generate them.  I do things like this all the time:

```
var base_selector = 'table#my-id tr.my-row-class '; // notice the space
$(base_selector + 'td.something').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

Comment: Purposely vague to stimulate some cursory ideas. :-) You and @ryanday are on the same track. See my comment on his post for some clarification.